# Dynamic Pictures are Not Showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, cordova

I have list of restaurants and I have to append pictures of each restaurant, which is coming from a database. For this I made div's id dynamic but the pictures not append on that div. If I make the div's id static then it shows the picture coming from the server. The problem is with making the div id dynamic. Please help me. Here is my sample code:

```
$("#list").empty();
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    if (data[i].has_logo == 1) {
        $('#pic' + i).css("background-image", "url('http://www.thefoodhive.com/web_root/provider_uploads/" + data[i].id + "/logo.jpg')");
    }
    if (data[i].has_menu == 0) {
        status = 'Call Now';
    } else {
        status = 'Order Now';
    }
    if (data[i].from_time == '' || data[i].from_time == null) {
        data[i].from_time = 'NA';
        data[i].to_time = '';
    }

    content = '<div ><div class="container"><div id="pic' + i + '" class="left"></div><div class="right"><div class="rightno">' + data[i].name + '</div></h4></p><i>Address:' + data[i].address + ',Timing:' + data[i].from_time + '-' + data[i].to_time + '</i><br><center><div style="float: right;"></div></div> <div class="bottom"><div class="btnleft" style="float: left;"><input class="callbttn" value="CALL NOW"type="button"></input></div><div class="btnright" style="float: left;"><input class="callbttn" value="' + status + '" type="button"  onclick="getdata(\'' + data[i].id + '\',\'' + data[i].has_menu + '\',\'' + data[i].phone_no + '\');"></input></div></div>';
```

Comment: do you have a live demo of your problem?

Comment: can we see what 'data' looks like?

Comment: please console.log(data); and see if it's empty else let us know the structure of the data

Comment: @AmitSoni yes i am posting

Comment: @AmitSoni[{ " id":"29"}]

Comment: @preetijakhar have you uploaded this code to your website, can you share your website link to us?

Comment: @AmitSoni sory this is for mobile app and its under development.can you just tell me how to make a div dynamic .i need a short example.just

Comment: @preetijakhar have appended `content` where you actually want to, for example: `$("#myDiv").append(content);` or `$("#myDiv").html(content);`

Comment: @AmitSoni thanks but amit i want to know if i dont know how many div i have.and i want to make div id dynamic .in that case .what i will do

Comment: @meho0o0o0o0 i posted

Comment: @preetijakhar the way you are doing now is fine

Comment: @AmitSoni its not done yet.what are you talking about.still i am unable to make div dynamic

Comment: @preetijakhar: please post your relevant script code, seems like you have not provided full script code

Comment: @JonasGrumann i posted data format

Comment: It's obvious that if the data item does not have has_logo the script will never enter to the line containing $('#pic' + i).css("ba....  So please provide the full data format or fix your get the data correctly :) so we can help you

Comment: Your data must looks like `[{id:29,has_logo:1,has_menu:0}]`...

Comment: @JonathanSimas hey you are right but the thing is.images are coming from another address .they are defibnately coming but my problem is my div shows only one pic if i give a static id to div .but when i try to give my div a dyanamic id then it sdo not shows pictures so please help me in that case generally i found that there is an problem in making div dynamic so help me

Comment: You are applying style to a div that doesn't exists yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying style to a div that doesn't exists yet...

Try to apply the background inline, like this:

```
     content = '<div ><div class="container"><div id="pic' + i + '"
 class="left" style="background-image:url(http://www.thefoodhive.com/web_root/provider_uploads/' + data[i].id + '/logo.jpg">...
```

Comment: thanks it solved my half problem.now i try to solve the another half and let you know.thanks alot